# Using Swift tuples as an alternative to multiple assignment

Tags: swift

Is there any performance impact or best practice conflict regarding readablity if I do this in Swift:

```
var (a, b, c, d) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Instead of this:

```
var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0
```

Comment: Is this question anything but opinion / religion?

Comment: For readability, perhaps. But it also infers a question regarding pattern matching once vs four times.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to be as clear (to other programmers) as possible with your code.

To be concerned about optimization at the level is just crazy. [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.".

Comment: And as a parentheses, "premature" means optimizing something before you know it's really the source of bad performance.

Comment: Furthermore, performance tuning on an early beta compiler is insane. Assume that common patterns with obvious optimizations will be optimized by the compiler as time goes on. In the above code, the compiler has access to all the required information on a single line; it can clearly get these two lines to be equivalent if there's an important performance impact.

Comment: I understand that readability takes precedence. That is part of the question - is this approach to multiple assignment unconventional?

Comment: No. In Ruby you'd do this all the time. And that sort of thing is exactly what this kind of multiple assignment notation is for.

Comment: But this is not Ruby.

Comment: @matt, this is different than multiple assignment in Ruby. In Ruby, I do `x, y = 2, 4`, which is different from using a tuple as an rvalue.

Comment: @ybakos No, not really. It's just a notation.

Comment: @matt, can you be more specific? Ruby does not treat comma-separated values as literal tuples like python does.

Comment: Well, there's nothing terribly "literal tuple"-like about this either. You can say `var x:Int; var y:Int; (x,y)=(1,2)` So it's not as if the parentheses are really _doing_ anything; there were never any actual tuple objects in the story, just a multiple assignment.

Comment: What is really interesting is (x,y) = (y,x), a swap without a temp.